# Target class [Controller] does not exists when defining API route using namespace in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel v8 and i tried to create an API route for admin authentication like this:

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->name('admin.')->namespace('Admin')->group(function(){
    Route::middleware('auth:admin-api')->group( function () {
        Route::resource('tasks', TaskController::class);
    });
    Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function(){
        //Login Routes
        Route::post('/login','LoginController@login'); 
        Route::post('/register','LoginController@register'); 
    });
});
```

when i tried to access `http://laravel.local/api/admin/login` i got this following error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [Admin\Auth\LoginController] does not exist. in file /Users/John/Sites/laravel/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 875

I already created the controller file in  **app/Http/Controllers/API/Admin/Auth/LoginController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\BaseController as BaseController;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Validator;

   
class LoginController extends BaseController
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing

Answer (score 0):

You created LoginController in App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\Auth namespace, but when you added route login in api route file, don't use the **API** namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You should update you code.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin\Auth\LoginController;

Route::prefix('/admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::middleware('auth:admin-api')->group( function () {
        Route::resource('tasks', TaskController::class);
    });
 
    Route::post('/login',  [LoginController::class, 'login']); 
    Route::post('/register',  [LoginController::class, 'register']); 
});
```